# Estimates for partial derivatives of harmonic functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, laplacian

I'm interested in proving the following:

Let $u$ harmonic in $\Omega $ and let $ B_{\rho} (x) \subset {\Omega} $  an open ball, then

$$
\left |{   u_{x_{i}}(x)               }\right |      \leq{  \displaystyle\frac{\gamma_{n} M}{\rho}                    },
$$
where $ u_ {x_{i}} = \frac {\partial u} {\partial x_{i}}$, $M=sup \left\{{ \left |{u(x)}\right |  : x \in B_{\rho}(x)                     }\right\}$ , $\gamma _{n} = \displaystyle\frac{2n \omega _{n-1}}{(n-1) \omega _{n}}$, and, $\omega_{k}$ is the area of the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R} ^{k}$.

**My attempt:**

Since $u$ is harmonic, we know that, for each  $B_{r}(x) \subset{\Omega}$  we have that
$$
u(x)=\displaystyle\frac{1}{Vol(B_{r}(x))} \displaystyle\int_{B_{r}(x)}^{} u(y) dy.
$$
However, if $u$ is harmonic then $u_{x_{i}}$ is also harmonic, thus
$$
u_{x_{i}}(x)=\displaystyle\frac{1}{Vol(B_{r}(x))} \displaystyle\int_{B_{r}(x)}^{} u_{x_{i}}(y) dy .
$$
If we use Divergence theorem, the above equation becomes
$$
u_{x_{i}}(x)=\displaystyle\frac{1}{Vol(B_{r}(x))} \displaystyle\int_{\partial B_{r}(x)}^{} e_{i}u(y) dS,
$$
where $e_{i}$ is the vector which has a $1$ in the $i$-th coordinate and zeros in all the others, it follows that
$$
\left |{  u_{x_{i}} (x)             }\right | \leq{  \displaystyle \frac{M_{r} Vol(\partial B_{r}(x))}{Vol(B_{r}(x))}   } = \displaystyle\frac{n M_{r}}{r},
$$
where $M_{r}=sup \left\{{ \left |{u(x)}\right |  : x \in B_{r}(x)                     }\right\}$.

Of course, I definitely want to take $ r = \frac {\rho (n-1) \omega_ {n}} {2 \omega_ {n-1}} $, but, as you can see, the problem with this idea is that I need to ensure that , for this choice of $r$, we have that $B_{r} (x) \subset B _ {\rho} (x) $. However, this is generally false :( , if we take for instance $n=3$, we have that $\omega_{3}=4 \pi$, $\omega_{2}= 2 \pi$ and so $r=2 \rho > \rho$ .
On the other hand, the hint of the book is consider the Poisson integral formula:

$$
u(y)=\displaystyle\frac{\rho ^2 - \left\|{y}\right\| ^2 }{\rho \omega _{n}} \displaystyle\int_{\partial B_{\rho} (0) }^{} \displaystyle\frac{u(x)}{\left\|{x-y}\right\| ^{n} } dS_{x},
$$
But, I definitely don't see why this formula is more useful :( .

Any help?

Thanks in advance.